# Azure Cosmos DB Java SDK support for Spring Boot 2.4.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any version of Azure CosmosDB Java SDK with full support for Spring Boot 2.4.x applications?
It is somewhat confusing because I found issues like this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/17692#issuecomment-761946453

That seems to state that the current updated version of Spring Boot (2.4.x) is not supported right now .

Please provide some clarification.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

2.4.x is not supported. Please use 2.3.x

Comment: We must use Spring Boot 2.4.x as it is the current mainline Spring Boot version. It is a requirement for us, we cannot step back all our development line to an older (non mainline) Spring Boot version. Which is the estimated date for releasing a version with support for Spring Boot current mainline (2.4.x)?